# Show inactive timestamps in Agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

**SCHEDULED** or **DEADLINE** **TODO** items with *active* timestamps correctly appear in my Agenda View (day/week/fortnight) under Org 9.0.4.

After making a timestamp *inactive*, such entries do not appear in the Agenda, as expected.

Pressing `[` in Agenda View should display inactive timestamps. However, pressing this does not change the View. A message is displayed indicating that inactive timestamps are now included, but none are included. I have tested this in day, week and fortnight views, both pressing `[` before and after changing the view. I tested with a DEADLINE item for today.

How can I display inactive timestamps in the Agenda?

Comment: Say did you ever receive a response on this question? I was looking at the same issue as well.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Say, I found that there is a variable `org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamp` that might fit the bill. I guess you include it in a custom agenda command. You can look at the docstring in emacs with `C-h v org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamp`.

Comment: The only difference between an active timestamp and an inactive one is that the inactive timestamp is purposefully excluded from the Agenda view. This is useful for time-stamping journal entries, etc. without cluttering your agenda with non-actionable items. If you want this to appear in your Agenda, just use the active timestamp instead.

Comment: @krishnab: The correct spelling is org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps, with an "s" at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint by krishnab a possible function would be:

```
(defun org-agenda-inactive ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps t))
    (org-agenda)))
```

And using `M-x org-agenda-inactive` for the new function.

Comment: Thanks. 

I did it one step further.

I use `C-c a` to call the normal org-agenda. And I use `C-c b` to call the org-agenda that show inactive timestamps, by adding `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'org-agenda-inactive)` to the .emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on top of the excellent solution from Slaven, I did it one step further.

I use `C-c a` to call the normal org-agenda. And I use `C-c b` to call the org-agenda that show inactive timestamps.

```
(defun org-agenda-inactive ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps t))
    (org-agenda))
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'org-agenda-inactive)
```